# Is BindingAdapter really saving our time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

I am working on new project and just started using Databinding. I heard people talking abaout code reduction.I have a RecyclerView in fragment. I have a simple ConstraintLayout in which I have 3 TextViews. This is in my Adapter for RecyclerView.

That aditional +" nazv" is just a sample and I could use String Extension.

```
    fun bind(item: Mkdo) {
        binding.txtMkdoNaziv.text = item.nazv+" nazv"
        binding.txtMkdoPost.text = item.post
        binding.txtmkdoPostNaziv.text = item.postNaziv
    }
```

ConstraintLayout for single RecyclerView row (deleted positioning properties)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintRowMkdo" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMkdoNaziv"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMkdoPost"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtmkdoPostNaziv"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This works just fine.
If I want to convert it to Databinding I have to add:

```
        fun bind(item: Mkdo) {
        binding.mkdo=item
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
```

And BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("setNazv")
fun TextView.setNazv(item:Mkdo?){
    item?.let {
    text="${item.nazv} nazv"
    }
}
```

ConstraintLayout for single RecyclerView row (deleted positioning properties) with Databinding

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintRowMkdo" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMkdoNaziv"
            app:setNazv="@{mkdo}""/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMkdoPost"
            android:text="@{mkdo.post}"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtmkdoPostNaziv"
            android:text="@{mkdo.postNaziv}"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This makes constraintRowMkdo nonreusable and in my opinion adds more work than without it.

Also if I have some string formatting I need to have it on two places string Extension and BindingAdapter. I can reuse Extension but it is still on who places.

What are your toughts on this?
Am I missing something?
Are there any aditional benefits of using it?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, i had the same thoughts so i tried out the Butterknife library and since then i only work with Butterknife, for me it makes my life really easier.

Comment: I always avoid using databinding. And like @DanielSpiess says, ButterKnife seems give us more benefit than databinding. For me, a layout should always be a UI without any code. So that whenever I update the code and my co-worker update the layout, we can do our work without interfering each other. Decoupling code and layout should be the priority.

Comment: Who said that BindingAdapter's purpose is to save time? Binding adapter simply enables binding a widget's attributes in XML, it can be for a variety of reasons but saving time is not one of them in my opinion.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous What are those reasons?

Comment: @solaza You can find some of them at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters). The way I see them are utils methods for Layout files. If you are using Databinding it will also enable you to write any presentation logic in the adapter if need to, but they don't have to save time or be re-usable.